# How to remove Rouge user group

Tags: users, groups

I was messing around with Apache and Webmin/Virtualmin and it created a new user.  I added my user to the new users' group.  It didn't yield the result I was looking for, so I deleted the user via virtual admin.

Now when I run `groups` I get the error `groups: cannot find name for group ID 1001`

How do I get the primary group from user 1001 OFF my user?

I have tried, `sudo groupadd --gid 1001 dummy` and then groups will put a dummy in the list, but then `sudo deluser me dummy` says I am not part of the group.

Next, I edited `/etc/group` and put my user in the group, then `sudo deluser me dummy` will work, but only to produce the same error `groups: cannot find name for group ID 1001`

How do I fix this? Where do groups get gid 1001 from???

Comment: What is the output of `sudo grpck -r` ?

Comment: I'll check when I get home today.

Comment: This is very strange, after a cold boot, the problem is gone.  The output of `sudo grpck -r` was nothing